# Share environment variables with www-data

Tags: shell-script, environment-variables, profile, lighttpd

I have a set of environment variables, which is created with a shell script `config` called from my `~/.bashrc`.

Having a new user `www-data` running a local webserver (with `lighttpd`), I need it to benefit from those environment variables. More specifically, the webserver runs `php` scripts which need them.

Therefore, I would like to move the call to `config` into a general file.

Reading the Ubuntu [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) related to environment variables, I tried to:

- write `export VAR="variable` to `/etc/profile.d/config.sh`, but when running the webserver scripts, the `$VAR` variable is not accessible.
- write `export VAR="variable` into `/etc/bash.bashrc`, but same issue

=> How can I share an environment variable between different unix users if I cannot make them logout (like `www-data`)?

Moreover, I need this environment to be loaded regularely (in case the configuration changes).

=> How can I be sure that the webserver `php` scripts are using the correct environment variables, without having to load the `config` inside every script?

Comment: What webserver are you running?

Comment: I'm using `lighttpd` (thanks for the comment, I'm updating the question)

Answer (score 1):

According to the lighttpd documentation at http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModSetEnv the correct way to do this is to use `mod_setenv` -

> **setenv.add-environment**
>
> Adds a value to the process environment (aka environment variables)
>   that is passed to the external applications:
>
> ```
> setenv.add-environment = ( 
>   "TRAC_ENV" => "lighttpd",
>   "RAILS_ENV" => "production" 
> )
> ```

Comment: thanks, but for my *set* of environment variables (that is subject to change anyway), is there an easier alternative?